# bibliography error when submitting to Scientific Reports journal

Tags: latex, submission, article, bibliography

I am submitting an article to Scientific Reports. I used overleaf to write the manuscript, with the SR template. Everything worked great. However, when I upload the main.tex file and the biblio.bib files to the platform, the bibliography does not show.

I am aware they are changing their submission system, but I must re-submit in the old one.

I do not have access to the compilation errors, since it is a submission platform that builds the pdf.

I was hoping someone had similar trouble and knows how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I simply had to copy the contents of the .bbl file into the .tex file.